# Multiple misfire on a 1998 Infinity Code

Tags: engine, misfire, infiniti

I bought a 1998 Infinity, and it has been running poorly, with a poor gas usage. I went and had a parts store run the computer, It gave me the code Multiple miss fire, along with Knock sensor, Evap canister purge ,and both oxy sensors. Can one problem make all the others go away, or can it all be these parts. I am not that good with the newer cars and all these sensors. Also, how can I check the plugs with

Comment: Welcome. We're going to need a little more information from you. Can you tell us which Infiniti model this is? Also, if you have the *exact* codes which were shown, can you post those. It seems you didn't really finish your question, either. Help us a little and we can surely serve you better.